# How to determine if Windows Media Player is installed when using WPF MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, media-player, mediaelement

I wonder if it is possible to determine if a Windows system has Windows Media Player installed.

WPF's MediaElement is a wrapper around it, so when Windows Media Player is not available it cannot be used to play content.

Is there a way to track if it is installed (hopefully without digging through the registry to see what is installed on the system)?

To make matters confusing, Windows 10 seems to have two Media Player installs that can be turned on or off, which do not seem to relate to the same thing. One is under `Settings` > `Apps & Features` > `Optional Features`, the other under `Settings` > `Apps & Features` > `Programs and Features` > `Programs and Features` (new window) > `Windows Features` (and in the list under `Media Features`). I believe the latter is the one WPF uses because I had this one turned off but the other one turned on and a MediaElement would not play until I set the 'off' one to 'on'.

Comment: Is MediaElement an absolute requirement? I personally would look for an alternative (preferably a Open Source / royalty free) one that doesn't have a Windows Media Player requirement. I haven't looked at this, but this was the top result I got when searching for wpf mediaelement alternative: https://unosquare.github.io/ffmediaelement/

Comment: Oh and as an answer to question: one thing I would recommend is maybe making it part of your Installer package as a prerequisite - such as a bootstrapper (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/deployment/creating-bootstrapper-packages?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Great out-of-the-box thinking! I was more thinking of having my app show a message notifying the user that functionality will be limited because Media Player is not installed, but your options are nice alternatives. I'll have to consider those, although when it comes to third party options I'd rather stay within WPF and use what it provides (if the right components are installed...).

Comment: I understand not wanting to go third party, but sometimes you just have to. Media Player seems to fallen out of favor over the years, and Microsoft has already made an 'alternative' that basically leaves MediaElement high and dry. With Media Player being required, I'm kind of surprised MedaiElement made it into .Net 5. ...

Comment: I don't really have an exact path to point you down, but Wpf has content to support Direct2d directly in Xaml / C#. Maybe you could go down that rabbit hole and see if there is any pure Wpf Direct2d media players.

Comment: @B.O.B. every alternative, including the microsoft one, have their own drawbacks. pick your poison